How to avoid using a relative path to include in c
It has been brought to my attention that it is bad practice to use relative paths to include.
Why is this considered bad practice?
How can I remove this from my code? It won't compile without it.
These are my include statements:
#include "../include/file.h"
#include "../include/parse.h"

I have my header files in an include directory and my .c files in a src directory:
Here is my Makefile, which is in the main directory of my project:
TARGET := bin/final
SRC := $(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJ := $(patsubst src/%*.c, obj/*.c, $(SRC))

default: $(TARGET)

clean:
    rm -f obj/*.o
    rm -f bin/*

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $?

obj/%.o : src/%.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@ -Iinclude

I'm new to C and using makefiles.

Since you already pass -Iinclude to gcc, that folder should be added to the search path. So you should be able to change #include "../include/file.h" to #include "file.h"

See What are the benefits of a relative path such as "../include/header.h" for a header?

Thank you for your comments. That is a very interesting post

"It has been brought to my attention that it is bad practice to use relative paths to include" -- absolute hogwash.  Relative paths are overwhelmingly the most common kind used with #include, and they always have been.  It is absolute paths that are poor practice.  However, it is more reasonable to take issue with the subset of relative paths that include one or more .. steps.  I think that's what you actually mean to ask about.

You've got OBJ set incorrectly in your makefile:
OBJ := $(patsubst src/%*.c, obj/*.c, $(SRC))

First, you don't need the * in the substitution as the % captures the remaining characters.  Second, you have .c in the result string instead of .o.
Change the above to this:
OBJ := $(patsubst src/%.c, obj/%.o, $(SRC))

